# Getting the ASP label Value and using it else where

Tags: asp.net

in the code there is this line

```
<asp:label id="lblGrandTotal" CssClass="BVSmallText" runat="server"></asp:label>
```

it returns a number, now there is no access to the `codebehind` .cs file

is there anyway for me to output the number into 
`<img src="//randomtracking.com/?v=<asp:the_total>"/>`?

or do I have to use java-script to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<img src="//randomtracking.com/?v=<% =lblGrandTotal.Text %>"/>`

[.NET Contractor](http://ryanpenfold.com)